# Android, can we find path for primary and secondary external storage programatically?

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard

Is there any API or any way to find out paths for primary and secondary external storage separately?

Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. 'Secondary external storage' is not standard (vendor extension). There are some environment variables that might be useful, but that is device/version/dependent. You can always check what is currently mounted and go from there.